# elasticsearch phrase_prefix search

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I'm using `query_string` for full text search and using `type` to define how to behave with full_text search, one of types that I have to use is `phrase_prefix`, to return documents that have exact term...

here is my problem:

when I want to search for one word terms.. such as `tea` the most documents that returns is because of `teacher`, I know for resolving this issue I have to use `phrase` type... but when I use this type for one word terms, I reach to another issue, for example `ui`.. 
because the most of documents consists `UI/UX` word, in `phrase` type search these docs will not return..

so I have a query that must behave like a phrase_prefix but not all the times... and the problem is I don't know the exact times!

if anyone have any solution for my problem.. I'll be so thankful to share that with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to solve this problem would be to use both queries connecting them together with **OR** in boolean **should** query. In this case, you would retrieve results in both cases. This means, that's still when you will search for `tea` you would get both `teacher` and `tea`, but since you would have for `tea` both clauses being matched - you should get higher score for `tea`. Same would work for `UI`

Example of the query would be something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        {
          ##query1
        },
        { 
          ##query2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That of course isn't ideal, but at least it would make you going.

More information about should clauses - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, it absolutely help me, I think without should query I can use function_score too, 
But if I could remove teacher from results it would be wonderful.. thanks

Comment: Making clear of teacher response would be much harder in general - cause then you would need some programmatic way of first checking if exact match is returning something, and only later sending more broad `prefix` query

Comment: Hmm.. complecated